# Cast an Object to its superclass in Java

Tags: java, casting, initialization, subclass, superclass

Learning Java here and I try to cast on a super class and i cant access to subclass methods, is it possible, I am doing something wrong.

I have this:

```
public class Musician {
      
  public String name;
  public String surname;
}

public class Instrumentist extends Musician{
  
  public String getInstrumento() {
    return instrumento;
  }
  
  public void setInstrumento(String instrumento) {
    this.instrumento = instrumento;
  }
  
  private String instrumento;
  public Instrumentist(String nombre, String name, String surname){
    this.name = nombre;
    this.surname = surname;
  } 
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Musician m = new Instrumentist("Antonio", "Vivaldi", "none");
  
    System.out.println(m);
  }
}
```

I know I can do Instrumentist i = new Instrumentist("Antonio", "Vivaldi", "none")
but then what is the purpose of Cast to superclass?

Comment: No, you are not doing anything wrong. No, you can't access subclass methods from superclass, unless you cast, that's how it works. About the purpose i would suggest to find some guides on core OOP concepts - abstraction, polymorphism, inheritance, encapsulation.

Comment: I just did an exam last week and now I am free and reading "Head First Java (Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates)" so i have this kinda "stupd" questions and for now its not clear for me. I know about polymorphism but can get sense about this special in my opinion case. Thx for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept is like this: 
The superclass/interface provides general implementation or a contract. The subclass overrides/implements that contract. 
To make sure that you can assign different implementations of that contract at runtime, you use reference of a Superclass and assign object of a subclass to it.
`Musician m = new Instrumentist("Antonio", "Vivaldi", "none");`

Here, with `m`, you can call methods defined in `Musician` class, but if your subclass has any other methods apart from those defined superclass, you can not access them using `m`. 
If subclass overrides any method, then even after using reference of superclass, say `m`, java would make sure that at `runtime`, overridden method in subclass is called.